# Validation message not displayed in active admin after renaming resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

My active admin's name was PartnerSite and after I added the validations the messages were prperly displayed. But after I renamed my active admin from Partner Site to Subdomain using ActiveAdmin.register PartnerSite, :as => "Subdomain" it is not displaying the error messages.

Comment: Can anyone give any solution for this?

Comment: activeadmin version ? can you please add source code eample to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: [Showing error messages in active admin for has many relationship table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395087/showing-error-messages-in-active-admin-for-has-many-relationship-table). It has link to a pull request and all you have to do (assuming you are using 5.0.1) is to add `f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys` in your form.